# mysqld ignoring my.cnf (mysql 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 Server)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-5.6

I installed mysql 5.6 on Ubuntu Server 16.04 using this method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762384/install-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

But i'm having trouble getting mysqld to read /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Specifically i'm trying to set it up for an Atlassian Confluence installation where I have to add in these settings:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_bin
default-storage-engine=INNODB
max_allowed_packet=256M
innodb_log_file_size=2G
```

I've checked `mysqld --help --verbose` and it has the my.cnf in its path.  Here's the relevant output:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf The following
groups are read: mysqld server mysqld-5.6
```

I know that mysql is reading the file because if I change [mysqld] to [mysql] the arguments are correctly printed when I run `mysql --print-defaults` also if I put a wrong line in the file mysql will fail to start and tell me where the syntax error is.  However mysqld does not report any arguments for `mysqld --print-defaults` or tell me about syntax errors in the file.

What else can I try?

### Solved:

my.cnf was a symbolic link.  I deleted it and made it an actual file.  Now `mysqld --show-defaults` is working!  So apparently mysql will follow the symlink but mysqld will not.  Good to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

my.cnf was a symbolic link. I deleted it and made it an actual file. Now mysqld --show-defaults is working. So apparently mysql will follow the symlink but mysqld will not.

Comment: Thank you so much! My default mysql installation created my.cnf as a symlink to /etc/alternatives/my.cnf, which in turn was another symlink to /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback. As strange as this setup was, editing this fallback file has no effect on mysqld since it apparently can't follow symlinks as you discovered. Why would the mysql installer ever set it up like this?

Answer (score 0):

For mysqld as I know only hard links works. Or maybe you just had wrong permission, on original my.cnf file to which you put symbolic link.